# Sending JSON Data with Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm building a chat app and I understand how to receive the data back but I'm having trouble sending the data. I'm trying to take two UITextField values which are the username and the message and send the data.

Variables

```
@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextField!
```

Request To Receive

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let parameters = ["user": username.text, "message": textBox.text] as! [String: String]

    //create the url with NSURL
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://website.com/getChatLogJSON.php")

    //create the session object
    let session = URLSession.shared

    //now create the NSMutableRequest object using the url object
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    //HTTP Headers
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        do {
            //create json object from data
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                print(json)
                // handle json...
            }

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    })

    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: What does not work? What errors do you get? By the way, why `.prettyPrinted`? The server doesn't care. And why `.mutableContainers`. It's meaningless in Swift. In both cases remove the `options` parameters. And in Swift 3+ it's `URL` and `URLRequest` and a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]`

Comment: What is the problem with sending the data over??

Answer (score -1):

Checkout SwiftyJSON, its a neat library for your JSON needs.

data insertion into the JSON object becomes as simple as:

```
json["name"] = JSON("new-name")
json[0] = JSON(1)
json["id"].int =  1234567890
json["coordinate"].double =  8766.766
json["name"].string =  "Jack"
json.arrayObject = [1,2,3,4]
json.dictionaryObject = ["name":"Jack", "age":25]
```

Here is the github page, all instructions are there https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

When it contains all data you need to put in, you can return the raw json in a string if you wish and send that which can be parsed

```
//convert the JSON to a raw String
if let rawString = json.rawString() {
  //Do something you want
} else {
    print("json.rawString is nil")
}
```

Comment: Kindly do comment a reason for down-voting as well :(